# Recycler View with multiple rows and columns - AutoFit like Flow Layout [Android]

Tags: android, layout-manager, android-recyclerview, flowlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I'm in a challenge to build a layout like this:

[image]

My first insight was to use a RecyclerView with an adapter that can deal with each item and inflate its layout.

So far, not so good.

I got this layout so far:

[image]

I can felling that I'm almost there, but really... I spend a week think about how to make it better, or just like the UI propose.

Some of my tries were

1. Use a grid layout and change max columns number depending on how many items there are on the list
2. StaggeredGridLayoutManager sounded like a powerful candidate to fix it and make me happy, but unfortunately when I tried to use it I realize that we need to pass a number of spanCount (columns) on constructor and I found some ways to work around this limitation changing the number of columns of each row, but I didn't like the final result, was not like I saw in other apps like Foursquare when you setup your interests.
3. I checked out this library [Flow Layout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout), but I not even started to use it, because I don't want to lose the whole recycler view power and I believe that there is a way to make it works! .....Even knowing that the library do exactly what I need.

Guys, I'm not here looking for some already done peace of code or someone to do my job. Actually I am looking for the light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: The staggered grid view effect... is that what you're missing here? Or is there more?

Comment: The staggered grid view constructor needs a span count when we instantiating, I don't want to fix a number of columns, I would like to fit layout according to item width row by row

Comment: Try this. `public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
}`

Comment: I am not in my laptop right now but I've tried this approach earlier and I realized that each item fit the whole row width

Comment: Did you try staggering horizontally?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I lost the vertically scrolling and I have to set a number of spanCount. I'm thinking about to develop a custom LayoutManager of StaggedGridLayoutManager

Comment: One of [these](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/41) might help you.

Comment: have you got your solution ?

Comment: Not yet, right know I am using recycler view with 2 columns. I saw many libraries that make exactly what I want, but I have not had the time to working it.

Comment: Were you able to get a solution of this using `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @RenanNery Have you got solution for this with RecyclerView ? I'm too looking for a Custom LayoutManager but didn't get it right enough.

Comment: Sorry @Gil nothing yet, still using grid

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Renan, could you post your code? I'm trying to do exactly what you are doing (a recyclerview with 3 items per line aligned on center

Answer (score 5):

Hello if you dnt want to use **recyclerview** there is another example using **custom Library** which acts like List [GitHubLibrary TagLayout](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout)

- **Sample Code**:

  ```
  mFlowLayout.setAdapter(new TagAdapter<String>(mVals)
     {
         @Override
         public View getView(FlowLayout parent, int position, String s)
         {
             TextView tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tv,
                     mFlowLayout, false);
             tv.setText(s);
             return tv;
         }
     });
  ```

**Using below code you can pre set selection you wanted:**

```
mAdapter.setSelectedList(1,3,5,7,8,9);
```

**Will show result like below:-**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to get this done using the new google material design library which contains a component called **Chips**. So you don't have to use a RecyclerView.

> A Chip represents a complex entity in a small block, such as a
>   contact. It is a rounded button that consists of a label, an optional
>   chip icon, and an optional close icon. A chip can either be clicked or
>   toggled if it is checkable.

**HOW TO USE THE COMPONENT :**

**1. Import the library**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

**2. Use code below**

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <!-- Your items here -->

     <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Item 1"/>

     <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Item 2"/>

     <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Item 3"/>

 <!-- End -->

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

You can find more details here : [Material components](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Answer (score 0):

It may now be too late, but you can also use google's [FlexBoxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

[Demo](https://i.imgur.com/QyfpZPM.gif)

Comment: You should add an example or more details instead of just posting a link.